# How to I select the DIV element next to my BUTTON element

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have 3 boxes, all with a 'click for more info' button.  I want to write as minimal JS as possible as I am unsure how many potential boxes I will have therefore do not want to write a separate function for each.

When I click the button on the first box it displays more info for the first box. When I click the button on the second box, it displays more info on the first box...

I have tried to find a solution to select buttons 'sibling'.

```js
$("button").click(function() {

  var x = document.getElementById("moreInfo");
  if (x.style.display === "none") {
    x.style.display = "block";
  } else {
    x.style.display = "none";
  };
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<section class="prices">
  <div class="row">
    <h2 class="prices-wp">Our Packages</h2>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col span-1-of-3">
      <div class="price-box js--wp-3">
        <div>
          <h3>Lake District</h3>
          <p class="price">£350+ <span>BEST OFFER</span></p>
          <p class="price-description">Perfect for those who know what they want</p>
          <button>Click for more</button>
        </div>
        <div id="moreInfo">
          <ul>
            <li><i class="far fa-dot-circle icon-small"></i>We do this</li>
            <li><i class="far fa-dot-circle icon-small"></i>We do this</li>
            <li><i class="far fa-dot-circle icon-small"></i>We do this</li>
            <li><i class="far fa-dot-circle icon-small"></i>We do this</li>
            <li><i class="far fa-dot-circle icon-small"></i>We do this</li>
            <li><a href="contactus.php" class="btn-full price-btn-full">Yes please!</a></li>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col span-1-of-3">
      <div class="price-box">
        <div>
          <h3>Wales</h3>
          <p class="price">£250+ <span>Discounts available via Facebook</span></p>
          <p class="price-description">Great for people who love sheep</p>
          <button>Click for more</button>
        </div>
        <div id="moreInfo">
          <ul>
            <li><i class="far fa-dot-circle icon-small"></i>We do this</li>
            <li><i class="far fa-dot-circle icon-small"></i>We do this</li>
            <li><i class="far fa-dot-circle icon-small"></i>We do this</li>
            <li><i class="far fa-dot-circle icon-small"></i>We do this</li>
            <li><i class="far fa-dot-circle icon-small"></i>We do this</li>
            <li><a href="contactus.php" class="btn-ghost price-btn-ghost">Book now</a></li>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col span-1-of-3">
      <div class="price-box">
        <div>
          <h3>D of E</h3>
          <p class="price">£150+<span></span></p>
          <p class="price-description">Perfect cadets</p>
          <button>Click for more</button>
        </div>
        <div id="moreInfo">
          <ul>
            <li><i class="far fa-dot-circle icon-small"></i>We do this</li>
            <li><i class="far fa-dot-circle icon-small"></i>We do this</li>
            <li><i class="far fa-dot-circle icon-small"></i>We do this</li>
            <li><i class="far fa-dot-circle icon-small"></i>We do this</li>
            <li><i class="far fa-dot-circle icon-small"></i>We do this</li>
            <li><a href="contactus.php" class="btn-ghost price-btn-ghost">Book now</a></li>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row more-info">
      <p>For more information on each package, click <a href="#" class="packageInfo" target="_blank">here</a>.<br><br>(This could contain a document with more in-depth prices)</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
```

I want the button to only show the related box's extra info.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The attribute *id* must be unique in a document, use *class* instead. You can target the specific element through `parent()` and `next()` and then toggle the *class*:

```js
$("button").click(function() {
    var x = $(this).parent().next();
    x.toggleClass('moreInfo');
});
```

```css
.moreInfo{
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<section class="prices">
  <div class="row">
    <h2 class="prices-wp">Our Packages</h2>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col span-1-of-3">
      <div class="price-box js--wp-3">
        <div>
          <h3>Lake District</h3>
          <p class="price">£350+ <span>BEST OFFER</span></p>
          <p class="price-description">Perfect for those who know what they want</p>
          <button>Click for more</button>
        </div>
        <div class="moreInfo">
          <ul>
            <li><i class="far fa-dot-circle icon-small"></i>We do this</li>
            <li><i class="far fa-dot-circle icon-small"></i>We do this</li>
            <li><i class="far fa-dot-circle icon-small"></i>We do this</li>
            <li><i class="far fa-dot-circle icon-small"></i>We do this</li>
            <li><i class="far fa-dot-circle icon-small"></i>We do this</li>
            <li><a href="contactus.php" class="btn-full price-btn-full">Yes please!</a></li>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col span-1-of-3">
      <div class="price-box">
        <div>
          <h3>Wales</h3>
          <p class="price">£250+ <span>Discounts available via Facebook</span></p>
          <p class="price-description">Great for people who love sheep</p>
          <button>Click for more</button>
        </div>
        <div class="moreInfo">
          <ul>
            <li><i class="far fa-dot-circle icon-small"></i>We do this</li>
            <li><i class="far fa-dot-circle icon-small"></i>We do this</li>
            <li><i class="far fa-dot-circle icon-small"></i>We do this</li>
            <li><i class="far fa-dot-circle icon-small"></i>We do this</li>
            <li><i class="far fa-dot-circle icon-small"></i>We do this</li>
            <li><a href="contactus.php" class="btn-ghost price-btn-ghost">Book now</a></li>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col span-1-of-3">
      <div class="price-box">
        <div>
          <h3>D of E</h3>
          <p class="price">£150+<span></span></p>
          <p class="price-description">Perfect cadets</p>
          <button>Click for more</button>
        </div>
        <div class="moreInfo">
          <ul>
            <li><i class="far fa-dot-circle icon-small"></i>We do this</li>
            <li><i class="far fa-dot-circle icon-small"></i>We do this</li>
            <li><i class="far fa-dot-circle icon-small"></i>We do this</li>
            <li><i class="far fa-dot-circle icon-small"></i>We do this</li>
            <li><i class="far fa-dot-circle icon-small"></i>We do this</li>
            <li><a href="contactus.php" class="btn-ghost price-btn-ghost">Book now</a></li>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row more-info">
      <p>For more information on each package, click <a href="#" class="packageInfo" target="_blank">here</a>.<br><br>(This could contain a document with more in-depth prices)</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
```

Comment: @JonathanAndrewFox, we can only help you based on the source in the question. It is really impossible to guess your code in your actual environment and answer......

Comment: the source is correct, yet it still does not seam to be working?

Answer (score 0):

this.parentNode.nextSibling gets to you moreInfo class div element.